# Is there a way to programmatically set a WTForm form field value at runtime?

Tags: python-3.x, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Basically, why doesn't this cause the `select` option to have a `selected` value?

```
>>> import wtforms
>>> class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
...     choice = wtforms.SelectField('A Choice', choices=[(1, 'hi'), (2, 'there')])
...     
>>> form = MyForm()
>>> form.choice.data = 2
>>> print(form.choice)
<select id="choice" name="choice"><option value="1">hi</option><option value="2">there</option></select>
```

It seems like the second `<option>` tag should have a `selected` attribute.

Is there a way to, at runtime, set the value of a wtforms field?

Comment: Read this as WTF Form.

Comment: Yeah... it's a punny project name.